# How to bind cascading Dropdown list using methods for countries and states in asp.net without using java script or Ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, cascadingdropdown

I need 2 Dropdown list's in which the second drop down list is populated based on the firstone without using any javascript or ajax and in how many ways can we achieve this? i tried using methods but i couldn't bind it.

here is what i tried

```
public List <string> indiacities()
{
    List<string> l2 = new List<string>();
    l2.Add("hyderabad");
    l2.Add("calcutta");
    l2.Add("chennai");
    return l2;
}
public List<string> usacities()
{
    List<string> l1 = new List<string>();
    l1.Add("newyork");
    l1.Add("new jersy");
    l1.Add("texas");
    return l1;
}      
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(DropDownList1.SelectedValue=="0")
    {

        DropDownList2.DataSource=usacities();
        DropDownList2.DataBind();
    }
    else if(DropDownList1.SelectedValue=="1")
    {
        DropDownList2.DataSource=indiacities();
        DropDownList2.DataBind();
    }
    else{}
 }
```

Comment: show what you've tried.

Comment: Some efforts please.

Comment: you dont bind to the method, bind to the list itself.

Comment: @prospector Can u give me a sample ?

Comment: I am a begginer,so please excuse my Questions

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, just to give you a general rough idea on how to assign a list as a datasource using your code.

```
    List<string> UsaCities = new List<string>();
    List<string> IndiaCities = new List<string>();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {

            UsaCities.Add("newyork");
            UsaCities.Add("new jersy");
            UsaCities.Add("texas");
            IndiaCities.Add("hyderabad");
            IndiaCities.Add("calcutta");
            IndiaCities.Add("chennai");

            DropDownList1.DataSource = UsaCities;
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
        }

    }
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {

            DropDownList2.DataSource = UsaCities;
            DropDownList2.DataBind();
        }
        else if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            DropDownList2.DataSource = IndiaCities;
            DropDownList2.DataBind();
        }
    }
```